# jQuery .one not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code that I use and many times it creating problem in Firefox & IE11.

```
$("#systemsetting").one("click", function(){
     var p = $(this).attr('href');
        var action = p;
        var form = $(document.createElement('form')).attr('action', action).attr('method','post');
        $('body').append(form);
        $(document.createElement('input')).attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "requestId").attr('value', requestId).appendTo(form);
        $(form).submit();
        return false;
});
```

Comment: What kind of problem? Any error occurred? Which jQuery version?

Comment: Actually i handle double click when user press double click it work as single click but on double click user getting logout from the application i am using jquery1.7.2 version thank you for answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$("#systemsetting").click(function(){
    var clicked = $("#systemsetting").hasClass("clicked");
    if(!clicked) {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        var p = $(this).attr('href');
        var action = p;
        var form = $(document.createElement('form')).attr('action', action).attr('method','post');
        $('body').append(form);
        $(document.createElement('input')).attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "requestId").attr('value', requestId).appendTo(form);
        $(form).submit();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: should probably move the if statement inside of the event handler